# What is the effect of new line after return keyword

Tags: javascript

I have an iife & a inner function.The inner function is returning an object in first case the `{` is immediately after the `return` keyword, in second case the brace `{` starts in a new line. In fist case the value is correctly returned and in second case it is throwing an `undefined` error

```js
(function() {
  function sayHello() {
    var name = "myName";
    return {
      fullName: name
    }
  }
  console.log(sayHello().fullName);
})();
```

```js
(function() {
  function sayHello() {
    var name = "myName";
    return 
    {
      fullName: name
    }
  }
  console.log(sayHello().fullName);
})();
```

I am not able to understand the effect statement in a new line after `return` statement & I am only guessing the return statement is getting terminated even though there is a statement in next line

Comment: This is known as automatic semicolon insertion.

Comment: If it were me, i'd just remove ASI from javascript. It's not a whitespace oriented language and such a thing is just making more confusion and bugs.